# Delphi bcd field in TDataset descendant

Tags: delphi, dataset

I am trying to write simple TDataset descendant. In overriden method GetFieldData(Field: TField; var Buffer: TValueBuffer) I fill buffer with actual values mostly using DataConvert function like this

```
case Field.FieldType of  
ftCurrency:begin
           C:=Some_Currency_Value;
         if Buffer<>nil then
           DataConvert(Field,@C,Buffer,True);
       end;
```

but it doesn't work for BCD fields. When I wrote

```
ftBCD:begin
         BC:=StrToBCD(Some_string_from_currency);
         if Buffer<>nil then
           DataConvert(Field,@BC,Buffer,True);
       end;**
```

it displays strange values. For example for value 7 buffer is filled with value 734.029

GetFieldData goes like this

```
X:=FData.ExtractRow(ix) as TMQueryData; //this is full record of my mem table 
fix:=FData.FieldIndex(Field.FieldName); 
case FData.FieldTypes[fix] of 
ftFloat,ftCurrency:begin 
C:=X.C[Field.FieldName]; 
if Buffer<>nil then 
DataConvert(Field,@C,Buffer,True{False}); 
end; 
result;=True;
```

ExtractRow is saying simple an array. Nothing complicated. So I take string value of field typing as currency, date, datetime, integer or other and then fill BUFFER with DataConvert function. The only problem is with ftBCD. I managed so far by convert bcd as currency to temporary TVaLueBuffer and then converting using DataConvert. It looks like this

```
TDBBitConverter.UnsafeFrom<Currency>(Currency_Value, Temp_Buff);
DataConvert(Field,Temp_Buff,Buffer,True);
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to go on here.  Surely what you should be testing is a "round trip" from Value -> SetFieldData -> GetFieldData -> Value.  So I doubt anybody will be able to help unless you add at least your SetFieldData and GetFieldData routine **in full** to the q.  And what method are you using to visualize your data such that you observe the buffer being filled with 734.029?

Comment: I'm using my own memory table. GetFieldData is very simple
  X:=FData.ExtractRow(ix) as TMQueryData;  //this is full record of my mem table
fix:=FData.FieldIndex(Field.FieldName);  case FData.FieldTypes[fix] of
    ftFloat,ftCurrency:begin
                         C:=X.C[Field.FieldName];
                         if Buffer<>nil then

                         DataConvert(Field,@C,Buffer,True{False});
                       end;
result;=True;

Comment: Well, put it in your q, please, also your ExtractRow.  SO comments are not permanent.